# What conflicts drive the plot in The Half-Blood Prince?

Tags: harry-potter

I can't think of them, because it's been a while since I read the book. All I've come up with is that Harry was trying to expose Malfoy and figure out where the Horcruxes are.

Comment: Is this a literature homework question? :)

Comment: @DVK - That's EXACTLY what I thought when I read this; the phrasing is a little to high-school homeworkish...

Comment: BTW, if you use the answer in your essay, I'd suggest honestly referencing it. Teachers can google too, AND they appreciate honesty :)

Comment: Isn't that the one where Dumbledoor is conflicted with Harry when they find out that D and Voldermort are brothers at Harmione's funeral?

Comment: @Stefan - NO SPOILERS!

Comment: @DVK, but the OP has already read the book? He/She might not remember the details but they would know about what happened on the cruise ship!

Comment: I'd like to see a teacher accepting this site as a legit reference haha

Answer (score 8):

- Doog vs Live
- Harry vs Malfoy
- Harry using HBP's book vs. Hermione's Girl Scout approach
- Dumbledore vs Voldemort AND Harry vs Voldemort, expressed as search for Horcuxes
- Snape vs Dumbledore over killing of Dumbledore (though we don't find that out 'til the end of *DH*)
- Harry's internal conflict over dating Ginny (driven by Ron's conflict over protecting her from dating as her older brother)
- Hermione vs Lavender over Won-Won
- Harry's internal conflict over dating Ginny because it puts her in danger as his pressure point
- Harry's conflict with McLaggen over the Quidditch team
- Harry's conflict with Snape over Harry being James and Snape being, well, Snape (culminating in Harry using Sectumsempra on Malfoy and Snape killing Dumbledore)
- Dumbledore conflict with himself over the Hallows - culminating in him fatally curse-poisoning himself (though we don't find that out till the end of *DH*)
- Not quite a conflict, but internal tension in Slughorn of shame over telling Riddle about Horcruxes vs. desire to help Harry in honor of Lily's memory.

Comment: Also, a minor one of Phlegm vs female Weasleys :)

Comment: .Doog vs. Live?

Comment: @Kevin - Read backwards.

Comment: And the downvote is for?

Comment: Malfoy VS Time (Voldemort pressure to kill Dumbledore).